# What is the meaning of depth data read by function: glReadPixels of glut ?

Tags: opengl, glut

I use the glut to display my 3D scene

```
glReadPixels(300,//xPos
             300,//yPos
             1,1,//size
             GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,//type is depth
             GL_FLOAT,//return type is  float
             &point);
```

I want to use this function to get the depth of a pixel.
But the returned data is always in range `[0,1]`, such as `0.999872, 0.999921.....`
How can I convert it to real depth (from an object to camera)

Comment: glReadPixels is part of OpenGL not GLUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use this function to get the depth of a pixel. But the returned data is always in range [0,1], such as 0.999872, 0.999921.....

The values are in the range set with glDepthRange. The default is [0, 1].

> How can I convert it to real depth (from an object to camera)

By projecting the screen space coordinates (what you have) back into world space. You can use [gluUnProject](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml) for this. The `model` matrix it accepts depends into which space you want ptoject. **OpenGL has no camera** so it all depends on the viewing matrix you define. You didn't show your drawing code, so I can't tell you at which point to take a copy of the modelview matrix to hold the view matrix you need.

Answer (score 0):

glReadPixels manual:

```
                    Depth values are read from the depth buffer.
                    Each component is converted to floating point such that the minimum depth
                    value maps to 0 and the maximum value maps to 1.
                    Each component is then multiplied by GL_DEPTH_SCALE,
                    added to GL_DEPTH_BIAS,
                    and finally clamped to the range [0, 1]
```